# Is it possible to parse python with python and extract executable expressions?

Tags: python

I'd like to parse a Python string (or object), and from it be able to extract its "parts."

For instance, given the following:

```
  def foo():
     xs = [x ** x
           for x in range(100)
           if x % 2 
     ]

     for x in xs: 
        print x 
        print 'cool'
```

I'd like be able to parse it into expressions like:

```
1.   xs = [x ** x
               for x in range(100)
               if x % 2 
           ]


2.     for x in xs: 

3.        print x 

4.        print 'cool'
```

From googling around, I found the `inspect` module, which can convert an object into its source via `getsourcelines`, but it's completely agnostic to python syntax. I'm looking for something that could parse out *expressions.*

1. Is this even possible?
2. Is there a library that does it?

Comment: If you open the source to be read you could just keep count of how far indented you are and use that to determine where new statements are at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a parser built in in the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html) module. It wont give you back exactly what you want in the form that you want, but the [ast.parse()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) method gives you back an abstract syntax tree from which you can construct what you're looking for, with a little effort.